# Assigning WP hooks to a class property

Tags: php, wordpress, oop

I am learning PHP OOP for Wordpress and the general way to add hooks in a class, mentioned everywhere, is:

```
add_action( $hook_name, [$this, $callback_name] );
```

But there is a plugin, when I opened its activator class, it first defines a protected property `protected $loader;`

And then the hooks below in that same class are grouped and called like this:

```
$class_name = new Class( $arg1, $arg2 );// this class was defined in another file
$this->$loader->add_action( $hook1_name, $class_name, $callback_name );
$this->$loader->add_action( $hook2_name, $class_name, $callback_name );
$this->$loader->add_action( $hook3_name, $class_name, $callback_name );
$this->$loader->add_action(...
```

And towards the end of this class it has:

```
public function run() {
    $this->loader->run();
}
```

So I am confused about the 3 observations here:

1. Why is `$loader` required here to run the hooks
2. Why isn't the second argument in the hook an `array`? The third argument should be `priority` of the hook but why here is the callback name  mentioned?
3. This `$loader->run()` function is not defined in the class so how will it auto-run all the hooks?

Thank you.

Comment: The author probably wanted a more "consistent" way to call `add_action` so they wrote a wrapper around the WP `add_action` function. **This would all be just a style of writing the code.** My guess is that `$this->loader->add_action()` will push those arguments to an array, as where `$this->loader->run()` will process said array and call `add_action` for each item in the array.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier thank you for the comment. But I figured it. Answer has been posted.

Answer (score 0):

These functions were defined deep in a different file and those 'add_action' functions aren't the WP add_action hooks but instead are a custom function defined in the same different file. Bad and confusing practice to name your custom functions on hook names. But yeah I figured it.